# will maven shade plugin pick up dependencies in a shaded dependency jar directly?

Tags: java, maven

My team has a project containing two modules, A and B, and B depends on A. Because of another dependency of B, I need to ensure that B depends on Gson 2.8, but Gson 2.2 is in A's dependencies. The problem is that, when I used exclusion tag in in dependency of A, like following, it didn't work

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Then I found that both A and B used maven-shade-plugin. And in A, `<shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>` was not set, so that gson 2.2 has been packed in A's jar. And I guess in module B, shade plugin probably selected the gson in A.jar directly, which is gson 2.2, and ignore both the maven dependency for gson 2.8 and exclusion for gson in dependency of A. I later add exclude setting directly in module A's shade plugin, and excluded gson 2.2 in A. Then I got corret final jar of B.

So my question is whether it's realy like what I guess, that maven-shade-plugin will pick up the dependent package in another shaded jar directly ingoring either depdency definition in current pom or exclusion of the dependency def of the shaded jar? And why? Or is it a bug?

Comment: First I would think about the shading. Why do both of these modules shade?

Comment: Not very sure about that. But Module A is a lib also used in other systems, so I guess that shade plugin was used to avoid conflict in other system.